# MySQL DATE_ADD() not working

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database I have a table containing some business offers. One of the columns is `expire`, which contains the date a certain offer expires.

I want to select all offers which expire in 10 days. Here is my code:

```
SELECT * FROM offers WHERE TIME_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAYS) = expire;
```

I want to select all columns from offers, where the expiry date is equal date now plus 10 days (so they expire in 10 days). MySQL doesn't let me do that, it marks "=expire" as an error

> Syntax error unexpected 'expire' (expire).

Why is that? ( I'm working on MySQL workbench btw)

Comment: It marks it as an error? What error? Post the full error description.

Comment: Where's your quote??  `'`

Comment: Is `TIME_ADD()` a function in MySQL? And are you looking for the offers that expire on the same **day**, or in 10 days to the exact **second**?

Comment: the title says DATE_ADD() which is a standard function in mysql, but the code contains TIME_ADD(), which is not. Is it one you wrote yourself? Or did you mean to write DATE_ADD()? There is also an ADDDATE() function, too, btw. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find all offers that expire in 10 days, but you're not concerned as to what time in 10 days that they expire, then you can use the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM offers 
WHERE DATE(expire) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAYS);
```

If however you want to find all offers that expire in 10 days, to the exact second, then you can use the following instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM offers 
WHERE expire = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAYS);
```

Notice how the first query uses `CURRENT_DATE()`, which will return only a date value - `2018-08-03`. Whereas the second query uses `NOW()`, which will return a datetime value - `2018-08-03 08:29:00`.

Answer (score 1):

replace INTERVAL 10 DAYS with INTERVAL 10 DAY